# How to reclaim unused space in SYSAUX tablespace in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I have 6gb file for SYSAUX table space in 18xe oracle database.

SYSAUX table space has 61% free space :

```
    select
       fs.tablespace_name                          as Tablespace,
       (df.totalspace - fs.freespace)              as Used_MB,
       fs.freespace                                as Free_MB,
       df.totalspace                               as Total_MB,
       round(100 * (fs.freespace / df.totalspace)) as Percentage_Free
    from
       (select tablespace_name, round(sum(bytes) / 1048576) TotalSpace from dba_data_files group by tablespace_name) df,
       (select tablespace_name, round(sum(bytes) / 1048576) FreeSpace from dba_free_space group by tablespace_name) fs
    where
       df.tablespace_name = fs.tablespace_name
       and df.tablespace_name = 'SYSAUX';
```

returns

[image]

So I would like to reclaim the 61% free space if possible.

## Attempt 1 :

```
ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE '...\XE\SYSAUX01.DBF' RESIZE 5000M;
```

But I'm getting the error :

```
ORA-03297: file contains used data beyond requested RESIZE value
```

## Attempt 2 :

```
ALTER TABLESPACE SYSAUX SHRINK SPACE KEEP 5000M;
```

Error :

```
ORA-12916: cannot shrink permanent or dictionary managed tablespace
```

## Attempt 3 :

```
ALTER TABLESPACE sysaux RESIZE 5000M;
```

Error

```
ORA-32773: operation not supported for smallfile tablespace SYSAUX
```

Does anyone know to relcaim this space please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find the datafiles which can be re-claimed.
Run the below query to identify the datafiles of SYSAUX tablespace which needed to resize.

```
set verify off
set pages 1000
set lines 350
undef enter_tablespace_name
column file_name format a70 word_wrapped
column smallest format 999,990 heading "Smallest|Size|Poss."
column currsize format 999,990 heading "Current|Size"
column savings  format 999999,990 heading "Poss.|Savings"
break on report
compute sum of savings on report

column value new_val blksize
col mxfile new_val mxfile

select value from v$parameter where name = 'db_block_size'
/

select tablespace_name, count(1), max(file_id) mxfile from dba_data_files where tablespace_name='&&enter_tablespace_name'
group by tablespace_name;



column cmd format a300 word_wrapped

select /*+ PARALLEL(64) */ 'alter database datafile '''||file_name||''' resize ' ||
       round((ceil( (nvl(hwm,1)*&&blksize)/1024/1024 )+200),-2)  || 'm;'||chr(10)||'exec DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP(45);'||chr(10) 
from dba_data_files a,
     ( select file_id, max(block_id+blocks-1) hwm
         from dba_extents
                 where tablespace_name='&&enter_tablespace_name'
        group by file_id ) b
where 
        a.file_id = b.file_id(+)
  and ceil( blocks*&&blksize/1024/1024) -
      ceil( (nvl(hwm,1)*&&blksize)/1024/1024 ) > 200
and a.tablespace_name='&&enter_tablespace_name'
and a.file_id  &mxfile
/

undef enter_tablespace_name
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I didn't get how am I supposed to do with this queries. If I'm not mistakedn, I already know which datafile need to be resized. It's 'C:\...\XE\SYSAUX01.DBF'. Can you please explain more ? regards